# Por que o elemento fixo perde sua posição quando é utilizado a propriedade transform?

Tags: css

Tenho um elemento com a posição definida como "fixed", quando aplico a propriedade "transform" para criar uma animação o elemento fixo perde sua posição (ao clicar no botão para animar isso fica mais claro).

Como corrigir isso?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => { 
     const container = document.querySelector('.container');
     container.style.transform = 'translateX(-100px)'
     setTimeout(()=>{
      container.style.transform = "";
     }, 1100)
  }; 
});
```

```css
main{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.container{
    width: 320px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #717;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    width: 320px;
    height: 70px;
    background: rgb(251, 255, 0);
    top: 0px;
}

button{
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fixed"></div>
  </div>
  <button>Animate</button>
</main>
```

Comment: Eu não consigo entender a mentalidade dessas pessoas que ficam negativando, qual é o problema? se eu não soube perguntar me ajude a melhorar a pergunta, não negative e saia correndo, se você não entende do assunto ou não vai contribuir de nenhuma forma com o problema, negativar não vai ajudar em nada.

Comment: Cara eu não entendi bem o que vc quis dizer com "perde sua posição" o que está acontecendo que não deveria? E sobre o voto negativo, não se preocupe, tem um usuário aqui que da Downvote em toda pergunta nova, principalmente se tive a tag CSS. O cara acha que com um Downvote ele ajuda em algo rss, prefere votar negativo do que perder 1 min tentando ajudar de fato

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara embora a resposta resolva o problema, não sei te dizer exatamente pq ao colocar o `transform` o elemento `fixed` perde a referência no `viewport` :/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para resolver o problema primeiro coloque uma `margem: 0` no `html e body`, isso vai evitar um "pulinho" que a animação está dando no inicio. Depois troque `position: fixed;` que posiciona o elemento relativo ao `viewport`, por `position: sticky`, que posiciona o elemento **relativo ao container pai**.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => { 
     const container = document.querySelector('.container');
     container.style.transform = 'translateX(-100px)'
     setTimeout(()=>{
      container.style.transform = "";
     }, 1100)
  }; 
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.container{
    width: 320px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #717;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.fixed{
    position: sticky;
    width: 320px;
    height: 70px;
    background: rgb(251, 255, 0);
    top: 0px;
}

button{
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fixed"></div>
  </div>
  <button>Animate</button>
</main>
```